# maven how to package jar with its dependencies tree?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven-assembly-plugin with jar-with-dependencies descriptor,  trying to package a spring boot based sdk which has no mainClass entry but depends heavily on third-party libraies, and it will be used in other project just like a normal jar library.  I never did that before, what I am trying to achieve is showing in the screenshot that my Jar library will show its dependencies just like org.apache.commons and poi.

1、my first question is how to have a jar library that will show its dependencies when it loaded into IntelliJ Idea?

2、my second question is when I use my packaged jar library in other project, it can not load its dependencies and throw FileNotFound Exceptions, how do I solve this issue?

Many thanks from an amature!

1、i tryied decompile my jar that was package by spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin, but it's too complicate that I can't even find my Java Class from other project.

2、i decompile apache-commons.jar, found out that it used maven-assembly-plugin but with its own custom descriptor, i can not find its descriptor files so I choose pre-definded descriptor jar-with-dependencies.

[I don't have enough reputation credits to upload image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Fg2.jpg)

Comment: You seem to have removed the screenshot. If it's important for the question, you want to upload it with the "embed image" link; please do not link to external images. If it's unimportant, please [edit] to remove the language referring to it (and probably also clean up English and formatting).

Comment: If you have a usual project you should not package a jar-with-dependencies which will be reused. Better is to create a usual jar with the appropriate pom file and use that.. A spring boot application which has been packaged with the spring-boot-maven-plugin can **not** being used as a dependency (it's packaged differently)..